# Confused regarding the usage of -init_ & self in a class

Tags: python, class

I first wrote the necessary code to get the information I wanted from the internet, and it works. But now I'm trying to make the code look a bit nicer, therefore I want to put it into functions that are in a class. But I'm a bit confused when it comes to the usages of `self` and `_init_`. Currently, the code isn't working as I want, meaning it isn't adding the information to my dictionary.

As I have understood, you have to add `self` as a parameter in every function you create in a class. But I don't think I'm using the `_init_` in a correct way.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Importing data from Nasdaq
page_link = "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/financials?query=balance-sheet"
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=1000)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "lxml")

# Creating class that gather essential stock information
class CompanySheet:
    # creating dictionary to store stock information
    def __init__(self):
        self.stockInfo = {
            "ticker": "",
            "sharePrice": "",
            "assets": "",
            "liabilities": "",
            "shareholderEquity": ""
            }

    def ticker(self):
        # Finding ticker
        self.tickerSymbol = page_content.find("div", attrs={"class":"qbreadcrumb"})
        self.a_TickerList = self.tickerSymbol.findAll("a")
        self.a_TickerList = (self.a_TickerList[2].text)
        # Adding ticker to dictionary
        self.stockInfo["ticker"] = self.a_TickerList
        print(self.a_TickerList)

    def share(self):   
        # Finding share price
        self.sharePrice = page_content.findAll("div", attrs={"id":"qwidget_lastsale"})
        self.aSharePrice = (self.sharePrice[0].text)
        # Transforming share price to desired format
        self.aSharePrice = str(self.aSharePrice[1:]).replace( ',' , '' )
        self.aSharePrice = float(self.aSharePrice)
        # Adding results to dictionary
        self.stockInfo["sharePrice"] = self.aSharePrice
    """
    def assets(self):
        # Finding total assets 
        totalAssets = page_content.findAll("tr", attrs={"class":"net"})[1]
        td_assetList = totalAssets.findAll("td")
        tdAssets = (td_assetList[22].text)
        # Transforming share price to desired format
        tdAssets = str(tdAssets[1:]).replace( ',' , '' )
        tdAssets = float(tdAssets)
        # Adding results to dictionary
        self.stockInfo["assets"] = tdAssets

    def liabilites(self):   
        # Finding total liabilities 
        totalLiabilities = page_content.findAll("tr", attrs={"class":"net"})[3]
        td_liabilityList = totalLiabilities.findAll("td")
        tdLiabilities = (td_liabilityList[24].text)
        # Transforming share price to desired format
        tdLiabilities = str(tdLiabilities[1:]).replace( ',' , '' )
        tdLiabilities = float(tdLiabilities)
        # Adding results to dictionary
        self.stockInfo["liabilities"] = tdLiabilities

    def equity(self):
        # Finding shareholder equity
        netEquity = page_content.findAll("tr", attrs={"class":"net"})[4]
        td_equityList = netEquity.findAll("td")
        tdShareholderEquity = (td_equityList[24].text)
        # Transforming shareholder equity to desired format
        tdShareholderEquity = str(tdShareholderEquity[1:]).replace( ',' , '' )
        tdShareholderEquity = float(tdShareholderEquity)
        # Adding results to dictionary
        self.stockInfo["shareholderEquity"] = tdShareholderEquity
        """
companySheet = CompanySheet()
print(companySheet.stockInfo)
```

All I want the code to do is for each function to parse it's information to my dictionary. I then want to access it outside of the class. Can someone help to clarify how I can use `_init_` in this scenario, or do I even have to use it?

Comment: your init does it have double _ or single _ ? its __ init __

Comment: Change `_init_` to `__init__`. These methods are called `dunder` methods as they have double underscores. The `__init__` method acts as a constructor for the class.

Comment: Great observation, I have now changed this. But the dictionary still has no values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**init** is a constructor, which is called along with the creation of the class object. Whereas, self is an instance of the class, which is used accessing methods and attributes of a python class.
In your code, firstly change:

```
_init_(self) to __init__(self)
```

Then, in the methods:

```
def share(self):
    # Finding share price
    sharePrice = page_content.findAll("div", attrs={"id":"qwidget_lastsale"})
    self.aSharePrice = (sharePrice[0].text)
    # Transforming share price to desired format
    self.aSharePrice = str(aSharePrice[1:]).replace( ',' , '' )
    self.aSharePrice = float(aSharePrice)
    # Adding results to dictionary
    self.stockInfo["sharePrice"] = self.aSharePrice
```

Similarly, in all the remaining methods, access the variable through the self keyword.
Now, you also need to call the methods which are updating your dictionary.
So, after you have created the object, call the methods through the object and then print the dictionary, like this:

```
companySheet = CompanySheet()
companySheet.share()
print(companySheet.stockInfo)
```

Probably it would work!

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my code in my original question to reflect your recommendations. But when I call the dictionary it still has no values

Comment: Hey! I have edited my answer, check it out, now it will work definitely!

Comment: Wonderful, now it works! Marked your reply as the correct answer